# Convergence of product of series to zeta function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, dirichlet-series

Consider the product of the following two partial series:
$$\left[\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n^s}\right] \cdot \left[\sum_{d=1}^{N} \frac{1}{d^{s^*}}\right]$$
When $\mathbf{Re}(s) > 1$, then in the limit as $N \to \infty$, the above expression converges to
$$\zeta(s) \cdot \zeta(s^*) = \zeta(s) \cdot \zeta(s)^* = |\zeta(s)|^2$$
Going back to the original partial series, we can rewrite the expression above as
$$\sum_{(n,d) \in M_N} \left[\frac{1}{n^s} \cdot \frac{1}{d^{s^*}}\right]$$
where $M_N = \{(n,d) \in \Bbb N_+^2: \max(n,d) \leq N\}$, and $\Bbb N_+$ is the set of strictly positive naturals.

Again, if $\mathbf{Re}(s) > 1$, then in the limit as $N \to \infty$, the above series converges to $|\zeta(s)|^2$, since the series converges absolutely [as explained in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/782872/product-of-zeta-and-its-conjugate).

My question is about changing the way the summation is bounded. Suppose that rather than bounding by $\max(n,d) \leq N$, we bound by $n \cdot d \leq N$. We can do so by defining the set $P_N = \{(n,d) \in \Bbb N_+^2: n \cdot d \leq N\}$, and looking at the series
$$\sum_{(n,d) \in P_N} \left[\frac{1}{n^s} \cdot \frac{1}{d^{s^*}}\right]$$

**Question:** for $\mathbf{Re}(s) > 1$, does the above still converge to $|\zeta(s)|^2$ as $N \to \infty$?

It's kind of strange, because in the first case we could decompose the series bounded by $\max(n,d)\leq N$ into a product of two series from 1 to $N$, and then see that each factor converges to zeta as $N \to \infty$. If we're bounding by $n \cdot d$, we can't split the product in this way. However, the two series both converge to
$$\sum_{(n,d) \in \Bbb N_+^2} \left[\frac{1}{n^s} \cdot \frac{1}{d^{s^*}}\right]$$
and since everything in sight is absolutely convergent, I would expect the two are equal and both converge to $|\zeta(s)|^2$.

Comment: You would be correct. When things are absolutely convergent, it doesn't matter at all how you reindex and sum things. I'll let someone else provide the details though.

Comment: For $\Re(s) > 1$, $\zeta(s)\zeta(\overline{s}) = \sum_{n\ge 1, m \ge 1} n^{-s} m^{-\overline{s}}$ converges absolutely and so changing the order of summation doesn't matter, which means for any sequence of sets $A_k \subset A_{k+1}$ with $\bigcup A_k = \mathbb{N}_{\ge 1}^2$ then $\zeta(s) \zeta(\overline{s}) =\lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{(n,m) \in A_k} n^{-s} m^{-\overline{s}} $